# Why copy constructor is called?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, static-cast

I have the test code:

```
struct A
{    
    A (){}

    A (const A & a)
    {
        std::cout<<"copy A";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    const A& a1 = static_cast<A>(a);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why copy constructor is called? 
UPD: added the description of class A.
Program output is: "copy A"

Comment: Because the `static_cast` creates a temporary object.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Provide link, please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: The most important question is: what's `A`? Where is it defined? I can imagine a bunch of cases where copy constructor is not called.

Comment: @M90 - `static_cast<B>(a)` obviously creates a new `B` from `a`. Now guess what `static_cast<A>(a)` does.